# Reducing the size of my natively deployed JavaFX application

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm writing an application with JavaFX and am concerned about the size of the .EXE file that I'll be natively deploying. The application that I have is not so big (all together less than 5M), but the Java Runtime is making the final installed directory well over 100M which compresses into a ditributable 44M file.

I've been running tests with 64-bit Windows (Java SE 8u77). To make the final executable smaller I've removed parts of the JRE that are unnecessary as outlined here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-8-readme-2095710.html

Here's what I've found:

- Complete JRE  : 45.0 M
- Stripped JRE  : 44.0 M

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make the distributable .EXE even smaller? All of the information I've found is at least 2 or 3 years old and maybe not so relevant anymore. I'm feeling like there's more that can come out of the JRE, but it seems that that would violate the licensing.

Does anyone have any experience using any non-Oracle distributions or any other ways to make the JavaFX app smaller?

Answer (score 5):

When using the javapackager, you can set to NOT include the JRE. This makes the native launcher use the local installed JRE (which might not be the best solution).

When using the javafx-maven-plugin, you just have to set a bundlerArgument:

```
<configuration>
    <mainClass>com.zenjava.test.Main</mainClass>
    <bundleArguments>
        <runtime /> <!-- dont include JRE, use installed one -->
    </bundleArguments>
</configuration>
```

When using the javafx-gradle-plugin, just set the runtime as NULL:

```
jfx {
    verbose = true
    mainClass = 'your.application.appname'
    appName = 'appname'
    jfxMainAppJarName = 'appname.jar'
    vendor = "My Company"
    bundleArguments = [
        runtime: null
    ]
}
```

When using the ant-style xml-file of the javapacker itself, just set this:

`<fx:bundleArgument name="runtime" value="" />`

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) and the creator of the [javafx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin).

Comment: I did notice this option, but I've yet to understand how it won't create far more problems than it solves. What happens if someone tries to install without having an appropriate JVM? I'm guessing it won't be pretty. Explaining what to do beforehand (e.g. install this version of Java) is a documentation nightmare. And.... it's been my experience that simply saying "Java" to ordinary people gets them freaked out because "it's such a security problem".

Comment: @SanderSmith Yes, thats very true. Some are using [JWrapper](http://www.jwrapper.com/) as a (paid) solution inbetween those. Maybe you want to try [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) instead. All have in common to now include the JRE inside your bundle. It is possible to combine already existing javapackager with launch4j-bundler (in the case of maven, by haven two profiles: one launch4j, two javafx-maven-plugin with special configuration).

Comment: @SanderSmith There is one question you have to solve for yourself: are you depending on the JRE installed by the user, or do you want to take that task away from java-frightened users by providing you own JRE inside the bundle (but having the security-risk of bugfixes). I personally tend to have the second option, because you don't have to deal with "different JRE-behaviour", makes it better to reproduce behaviour. For updating: ;) some users are having a better feeling about software often gets updates, some don't.

Answer (score -2):

**One of the best tools for this is [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).**

Run your program through it before generating an executable

Comment: What are you suggesting? Simply running Proguard against my application is pointless because it's so tiny compared to the Java Runtime. Does anyone have any experience shrinking the Java Runtime? Is this even legal as far as the licensing is concerned?

Comment: Currently stripping down the JRE is a violation of the license agreement. With Java 9 (project jigsaw) it will be possible though.

Comment: Java 9 is a year away. Is there anything that can be done today to address this?

Comment: @EugeneRyzhikov the JRE is stripped down by the tools provided by Oracle itself. They are generating some stripped down JRE while packaging everything.

Comment: I agree, that Proguard does nothing but strip *ones own* code down to a minimum, which is not the issue here. As [@Sander Smith] suggest, there seems to be valid ways to remove some parts of the JRE. Maybe a tool like [jWrapper](http://www.jwrapper.com/guide-javafx-and-jre-stripping.html) could be of use? It is really hard to find something. Nevertheless: There are already builds of Java 9. You could use this to package your application. Java8-JDK includes a tool called *jdeps* maybe have a look [here](http://blog.codefx.org/java/dev/how-java-9-and-project-jigsaw-may-break-your-code/)

Comment: I've stripped everything that Oracle allows except for a handful of files that deal with internationalization that I need. Have others created executables with these methods and if so, what was the size of the files? As for Java 9, that sounds kind of risky. Does Oracle allow you to distribute things built with Java 9 yet?